# How to open Cesium 3D tiles with QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, tiles, 3d, format

How to open Cesium 3D Tiles with Qgis
The format is not available but this is an OGC standard:
https://www.ogc.org/standards/3DTiles

GeoPackage seems to be working on adding the extension:
https://www.compusult.com/html/OGC/3DTile_GeoPackage_Ext_Draft.html

Answer (score 4):

At the moment (QGIS 3.12.x),
3D Tiles is not yet implemented but this is planned.

Source:
https://hub.packtpub.com/new-qgis-3d-capabilities-and-future-plans-presented-by-martin-dobias-a-core-qgis-developer/

Answer (score 0):

3D Tiles are now supported - since QGIS 3.34 (released in 2023).

To add 3D Tiles datasets, you can use Data Source Manager (look for "Scene" tab) or Browser panel ("Scenes" top-level item).

More details: https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2023/11/16/3d-tiles-in-QGIS/